# FLV video tagging using ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server, html5-video

I would like to tag some parts on screen (like tagging people's head in photos in Facebook) in video (in certain second). Videos are in FLV format, video on demand. Is there any library that I can use to tag the video? or I can only use a cue point?

Environment:

1. Flash Media Server
2. Flash CS4 (ActionScript 3)

Other information can be further given. Ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NO direct solution of this issue. I end up have to record the time in a Flash embedding the movie player and make tagging actions there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a library (which doesn't mean there isn't any), but you could do it with cuepoints:
Create cuepoints in your video (either on encoding, or put them in on runtime via actionscript cuepoints) that have x, y, width, height as params, maybe also a duration and description.

Type for encoding cuepoints probably would be navigation, so you can get the nearest Cuepoint on seeking.
Then you need actionscript to listen for your cuepoints, and then draw those rectangles as an overlay over the video.